# Install and configure Apache PHP and MySQL in different computer

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Based on my project I am supposed to install Apache, PHP and MySQL on three different computers like Apache should be installed in pc1 PHP in  pc2 and MySQL in pc3. so how to configure this that apache should recognize PHP from pc2 and MySQL from pc3?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate MySQL on different PC, but for Apache and PHP, I think you should configure it on one PC.

You can use both two PC for web server which contains Apache and PHP then adds a load balancer to one of those servers.

Comment: yes you are right , I installed MYSQL in pc1 and Apache with PHP in pc2 it is working fine . but now the problem is how can I separate PHP from Apache .

Answer (score 0):

server 1 - runs httpd, any php request forward to server that runs php-fpm

server 2 - runs PHP-FPM

server 3 - runs MYSQL